# Low-cost, low-range RF transceivers

Tags: rf, wireless, transceiver

Basically I need a low-cost wireless communications module. My requirements would be ~10bit/s , ~2-3m range and up to 1$ for each. Can be receiver and transmitter separately as well. I think it should be working in 433Mhz band.

And suggestions?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-link-a-few-microcontrollers-wirelessly-at-low-speeds

Comment: cannot use irda.

Comment: Why not irda? It meets all that you asked for.

Comment: There may be things in front/between receiver and transmitter. For example, the transmitter can be under a desk.

Comment: @Arturs: You can edit your own questions and include updates like you did with your comment. This way the question is much more easy to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chipcon/TI [CC110L](http://www.ti.com/product/cc110l) (transceiver), CC113L/CC115L (transmitter/receiver).

Flexible sub-1GHz radio.

[Claimed to cost $1](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/analog/sub_1_GHz_low_power_rf_ic/index.shtml?DCMP=rfvalueline&HQS=Other+OT+rfvalueline-pr) for pair of chips in volume.

A [cheap devkit](http://www.43oh.com/2011/11/cc110l-rf-module-booster-pack-released/) is available.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for bringing these to my attention - amazingly well priced for what they do. Digikey stock them. Look like a nice low cost solution for some applications || 
You have two down votes for no reason that's obvious - but 3 upvotes including one from me. I gain the impression that there are idio... er ... people wandering around semi randomly down voting with no good cause. Feeling of power perhaps. It takes points off them and you get more points per upvote than a downvote (I think) so all is well.

Comment: It is a good choice for a production line, but the package is too small for prototyping.

Comment: @Arturs the devkit is a chip on a PCB, breaking out the SPI bus and power to pins

Comment: @Arturs You are unlikely to find what you are looking for at the price you want. As the volume increases, the price will decrease, but typically so will the part footprint size

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to [Low powered wireless doorbell & door open/closed sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22683/low-powered-wireless-doorbell-door-open-closed-sensor/22689#22689). I think my [Wicked Node](http://node.wickeddevice.com) / [Receiver](http://receivershield.wickeddevice.com) product is basically exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: His target price is "up to $1" which seems about an order of magnitude lower than your offering. Your offering may well be good value for what it does, but his spec is much lower than what you offer and he wants a price to match.

Comment: @Russell either I missed that or the price wasn't included in the original question, I'll withdraw my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used [Hope Microelectronics radio modules](http://www.hoperf.com/) which are cheap and worked fine.

Before buying the radio modules from personal experiences I would like to suggest you to think about what in your project is essential. If you would like to just transmit some data over a given distance (develop the logic on application layer) then think about how much your time costs and if it is better to spend time to develop the whole logic from data layer up to application layer or is it better to get more expensive module which already has implemented the protocols for two way communication - multiple acces, packet handling etc. and have more time to focus on your application.

Comment: these are also not < $1, but I agree they are pretty nice - also agree that it's non-trivial to build a wireless system from the ground up (i.e. starting with a bare radio)